# Show AlertDialog using try and catch

Tags: java, android, android-studio, try-catch

I want to check when i have connection to a server and to do this, i am using this code i found on internet, i don't know how to implement it, how to show an alert dialog or any kind of warning when i don't have connection. Any help would be appreciated!

CODE:

```
public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
    try {
        URL myUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        connection.connect();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle your exceptions
        return false;
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta, PID: 11573
                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.Reportes.onMapReady(Reportes.java:195)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                                        at er.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951434:20)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bf.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951434:5)
                                                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bc.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951434:5)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This is the code where it retrieves the info from the db, using PHP, and here also where the catlog sends me to
CODE:

```
       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = null;
        String url = "http://app/get.php";
        try {

            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getHttpGet(url));
            location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("id", c.getString("id"));
                map.put("campo_latitud", c.getString("campo_latitud"));
                map.put("campo_longitud", c.getString("campo_longitud"));
                map.put("campo_categoria", c.getString("campo_categoria"));
                map.put("campo_estado", c.getString("campo_estado"));
                location.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String campouno = "";
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(campouno)) {
            double campo_latitud = Double.parseDouble(campouno);
        }
   String campodos = "";
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(campodos)) {
            double campo_longitud = Double.parseDouble(campodos);
        }

            for (int i = 0; i < location.size(); i++) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(location.get(i).get("campo_latitud").toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(location.get(i).get("campo_longitud").toString())) {
                    campo_latitud = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("campo_latitud").toString());
                    campo_longitud = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("campo_longitud").toString());
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (isConnectedToServer("http://yourserver.com", 60)) {
   new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setTitle("Connected")
      .setMessage("You are connected to server")
      .create().show();
} else {
   new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setTitle("Not Connected")
      .setMessage("You are not connected to server")
      .create().show();
}
```

**Update:**

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); //do your instance creation here to avoid nullpointer if your try-catch go to catch.
    String url = "http://app/get.php";
    try {

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getHttpGet(url));
```

Comment: Using this one, it only show the message when its connected but the app stops when there's no connection

Comment: Can you show the log what error are you encountering?

Comment: It seems that you're doing something on the else statement other than showing dialog. The error is pointing on your ArrayList that is being null. Can you show your code on how you implement this?

Comment: Basically this is the first thing to do on the app, then there's an array where it retrieves from a database some info like name, address, etc. let me update the post.

Comment: try to initalize the array once you declare it: `ArrayList<Object> yourArrayList = new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: Now by doing that (Your update), the app doesn't stop, but it sends the same message ("Not connected") even when it is connected

Comment: The problem will the be code you're using when checking if it's connected to the server. Try to search first for other code, my answer solves your question on how to use it to show dialog.

Comment: OK, thanks buddy! im going to check the code and see what going on, thanks again for the time!

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean isConnected = isConnectedToServer("Your server", 10);

if(isConnected){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage("You are Successfully Connected"
                            + getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface 
                                             dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }).show();
}
else{
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage("Something Went Wrong!!"
                            + getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface 
                                            dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }).show();
}
```